# Error on Excel importing 

Tags: excel, powerbuilder

I am trying to import around 1500 Excel files to my system. 
The code is working in a loop and I am able open and import around 600 Excel files. After that I am getting an error message like: Error calling external object function open at line 55.....

I really stuck with this issue, if anyone can help that will be grateful.

---

Code posted in reply comments:

```
For ll_LoopCnt = 1 To Dw_1.rowcount( )
    Ls_File_Name = Dw_1.getitemstring( ll_LoopCnt, "file_name")
    Ls_Path =Dw_1.getitemstring( ll_LoopCnt, "file_path")
    ll_Sr_No= Dw_1.getitemNumber( ll_LoopCnt, "sr_no")
    ldt_File_Date= Dw_1.getitemDateTime( ll_LoopCnt, "file_date")
    Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = "False"
    Excel.WorkBooks.Open( Ls_Path )
    Excel.Application.Visible = False
    Excel.windowstate = 2 // 1 : Normal, 2 : Minimize, 3 : Maximize
    Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Lb_sheet_rtn = excel.worksheets(7).Activate
    Ls_ClipBoard = clipboard()
    Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
    Excel.Worksheets(7).UsedRange.Copy
    ll_cnt = ds_1.importclipboard()
    IF ll_cnt <= 1 THEN
        Messagebox("Error", "Could not find.")
    Else
        Dw_1.Scrolltorow( ll_LoopCnt )
        Dw_1.SetItem( ll_LoopCnt, "status", 'Success')
        For ll_Inner_LoopCnt = 1 To Ds_1.RowCount( )
            Ds_1.Object.file_path[ll_Inner_LoopCnt] = Ls_Path
            Ds_1.Object.file_name[ll_Inner_LoopCnt] = Ls_File_Name
            Ds_1.Object.file_sr_no[ll_Inner_LoopCnt] = ll_Sr_No
            Ds_1.Object.file_date[ll_Inner_LoopCnt] = ldt_File_Date
        Next
    END IF
    Clipboard(ls_ClipBoard)
    Ds_1.Reset( ) //Reset the data store
    Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
    Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False);
    Excel.Application.Quit
    Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    IF ll_LoopCnt = ll_Excel_Cnt Then //--->> After 100 files reset the memmory
        ll_Excel_Cnt = ll_LoopCnt + 100
        Excel.DisConnectObject()
        DESTROY excel
        DESTROY TEst_Excel
        GarbageCollect ( )
        Excel = Create OLEObject
        Test_Excel = Create OLEObject
        Li_rtn = excel.ConnectToNewObject("excel.application")
        IF li_rtn <> 0 THEN
            MessageBox('Excel error','can not run Excel Program')
            DESTROY Excel
            RETURN 0
        END IF
    End IF
Next
Excel.displayalerts = False
Excel.Application.Quit
Excel.displayalerts = True
Excel.DisConnectObject()
DESTROY Excel
DESTROY Test_Excel /* This is the code i written i dont think the OLE is crashing i think the connnectto the OLE is getting lost after some time, but stile its going fine for almost 600 records.. */
```

Comment: Can you tell if that error message is coming from Excel, or from your application? Is it possible to see which Excel file is causing the problem, and can that file be independently opened in Excel?

Comment: actually its not the problem of excel because i deleted that file and again try to post and ia getting the same error message after 600 imports.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the line of code would help, but this error message typically (in the context of OLE, which I'm guessing is the case here) comes from PowerBuilder making an OLE call which the OLE host rejects. From the information you've supplied, it's impossible to tell if the OLE host has crashed and isn't responding anymore, or if you've got the OLE host into a state where these functions are no longer applicable, or if the OLE object has become invalid, or what.

If it were me, and it was happening consistently, I'd run the app in the debugger to get to the state where the error is about to happen (you can set advanced attributes in breakpoints to not have a breakpoint activate every time it is passed) and try interrogating the OLE objects. I'd expect you'd also have to throw in some test code, since I'm not confident everything you'd want to test would be available to the debugger.

---

**New Feb 21**

I'd also change the set of files being processed, so that I could tell if the key to the crash is a specific file, or the quantity of files processed. For example, if you get rid of the first 100 files, does it still crash on the 600th file (same quantity) or the 500th file (same file)?

One possibility is that you're running out of memory. Each "dot" in an OLE reference (attribute access, method call) creates an object in memory that isn't destroyed until the garbage collect. The code clip you've posted will never enter the block where the GarbageCollect() is called (ll_Excel_Cnt is never initialized), so you might want to make sure that part is working. I'd also get rid of unnecessary calls. For example, you've got several calls that maintain the state of Excel within the loop (e.g. Excel.Application.Visible), when they only need to be called once. I'm also not clear from the code clip why you'd need to call a Save(), either time; this could be expendable as well. This clean up should also make your code run faster.

---

Good luck,

Terry

Comment: i tried to copy the code but this one allows me only few characters only.

Comment: For ll_LoopCnt =  1 To Dw_1.rowcount( )   
Ls_File_Name = Dw_1.getitemstring( ll_LoopCnt, "file_name") 
Ls_Path =Dw_1.getitemstring( ll_LoopCnt, "file_path")  
ll_Sr_No= Dw_1.getitemNumber( ll_LoopCnt, "sr_no")  
ldt_File_Date= Dw_1.getitemDateTime( ll_LoopCnt, "file_date")  
 Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts  = "False"
Excel.WorkBooks.Open( Ls_Path )  
 Excel.Application.Visible    = False
 Excel.windowstate     = 2 // 1 : Normal, 2 : Minimize, 3 : Maximize
 Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False  
 
 Lb_sheet_rtn = excel.worksheets(7).Activate

Comment: Ls_ClipBoard  = clipboard()  
Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save()   
Excel.Worksheets(7).UsedRange.Copy 
ll_cnt = ds_1.importclipboard()  
IF ll_cnt <= 1 THEN
Messagebox("Error", "Could not find.") 
Else  
Dw_1.Scrolltorow( ll_LoopCnt )
Dw_1.SetItem( ll_LoopCnt, "status", 'Success')  
For ll_Inner_LoopCnt =  1 To Ds_1.RowCount( ) 
Ds_1.Object.file_path[ll_Inner_LoopCnt]   = Ls_Path
Ds_1.Object.file_name[ll_Inner_LoopCnt]   = Ls_File_Name 
Ds_1.Object.file_sr_no[ll_Inner_LoopCnt]   = ll_Sr_No 
Ds_1.Object.file_date[ll_Inner_LoopCnt]   = ldt_File_Date
Next

Comment: END IF
Clipboard(ls_ClipBoard) 
Ds_1.Reset( )  //Reset the data store
Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save()  
Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False); 
Excel.Application.Quit 
Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False  
IF ll_LoopCnt = ll_Excel_Cnt Then  
//--->>  After 100 files reset the memmory 
ll_Excel_Cnt = ll_LoopCnt + 100
Excel.DisConnectObject() 
DESTROY excel 
DESTROY TEst_Excel 
GarbageCollect ( )  
Excel   = Create OLEObject
Test_Excel = Create OLEObject 
Li_rtn = excel.ConnectToNewObject("excel.application")

Comment: IF li_rtn <> 0 THEN
 MessageBox('Excel error','can not run Excel Program') 
 DESTROY  Excel 
 RETURN  0
END IF
End IF 
Next 
Excel.displayalerts = False 
Excel.Application.Quit
Excel.displayalerts = True  
Excel.DisConnectObject()

DESTROY Excel  
DESTROY Test_Excel   /* This is the code i written i dont think the OLE is crashing  i think the connnectto the OLE is getting lost after some time, but stile its going fine for almost 600 records.. */

Comment: You can preserve the formatting of your code by editing your original question and putting the code in there.

Comment: I've posted your code into your original question, but we still don't know which line is crashing; line 55 of the code you've posted is at the end of the script.

Comment: Thanks for the Replay, ll_Excel_Cnt variable is initialized to 100 at the starting time itself, i didnt mentioned that part in the code here.  Thanks for the Suggestions for the save calls, actually i written that code just for some checking purpose.   The control is going in to that loop and i can see in the task manager that the EXCEL.exe is getting refreshing at each 100th file. I cant understand what is actually happing over there.

Answer (score 0):

Around line 30 you have

```
Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False);
Excel.Application.Quit
```

You shouldn't call `Excel.Application.Quit` there. Also, I always recommend to put anything that uses OLE inside a Try..Catch block and catch OleRuntimeError and RuntimeError.

Comment: Thanks for the Replay let me try that..I rectified that issue, actually i still dont know what the issue was, i declared a new excel OLE Object and before opening each file Iam connecting to that file using OLE.ConnectToObject( /*file name*/ ) if the connection is not there again connect the OLE using the excel.ConnectToNewObject("excel.application")  command, now the code  is working fine